# Как пропарсить json строку с вложенными массивами

Tags: php, json

Ребята помогите научиться работать с json строками

Апи выдает мне такой результат:

```
{"result":{"total":2730,"data":{"ok_delivered":2564,"ok_read":114,"ok_link_visited":45,"err_user_inactive":1,"err_spam_rejected":3,"err_delivery_failed":3}}}
```

Что мне необходимо сделать что бы работать с данными в таком формате, к примеру я хочу вывести значение total или ok_delivered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = '{"result":{"total":2730,"data":{"ok_delivered":2564,"ok_read":114,"ok_link_visited":45,"err_user_inactive":1,"err_spam_rejected":3,"err_delivery_failed":3}}}';
$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->result->data->ok_delivered;
```

Результат: 2564

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Использовать php функцию  [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$data = json_decode('{"result":{"total":2730,"data":{"ok_delivered":2564,"ok_read":114,"ok_link_visited":45,"err_user_inactive":1,"err_spam_rejected":3,"err_delivery_failed":3}}}');
echo $data->result->total;
echo $data->result->data->ok_delivered;
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '{"result":{"total":2730,"data":{"ok_delivered":2564,"ok_read":114,"ok_link_visited":45,"err_user_inactive":1,"err_spam_rejected":3,"err_delivery_failed":3}}}';
echo json_encode($string, true)['result']['total'];// 2730
```